# Inheritance in Java and Object Types

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm currently studying a book for the AP CS A exam, specifically the Barron's book for test preparation.

One section of the book refers to two classes, `Student` and `GradStudent`, where `GradStudent` `extends` `Student`.

`GradStudent` has the method `getId()` while `Student` does not.

If I were to run the following code:

```
Student s = new GradStudent()
s.getId()
```

The book informs me that I would get an error. Why is this? Since I am initializing it as a `GradStudent`, wouldn't `s` have access to the method `getId()`?

Essentially, if I declare a variable as the superclass, and initialize it to the subclass, what happens?

In other words, how do `s` and `g` in the following example differ:

```
Student s = new GradStudent()
GradStudent g = new GradStudent()
```

EDIT:

I've now understood that `s` only has access to the methods in the `Student` class.
So what happens if I do the following:

```
Student s = (new GradStudent().setId(1) )
```

What happens to the `id` field? (Assuming it is only present in the `GradStudent` class) If I casted `s` to `GradStudent` again, would it be able to access the same `id`?

Comment: Yea but the java compiler don't know an method _getId()_ in class Student. To use this method cast s to GradStudent again: `GradStudent gs = (GradStudent) s; gs.getId()`

Comment: "*Since I am initializing it as a `GradStudent`, wouldn't s have access to the method `getId()`?*" - No, it would not. You see it as a `Student`, therefore you can only see what a `Student` has. The terms you are looking for are most probably "static type" and "dynamic type".

Comment: @Logan If I initialized the `GradStudent` variable with some variables present only in the `GradStudent` class, what would happen if I casted it to a `Student`?

Comment: While it may be apparent to us as code readers your intention, the compiler makes no such distinction and only sees a Student s with its available methods. As an aside, imagine if you had `Animal a` and assigned it, at random, either `Bird`, `Dog`, or `Cat`. You would not be able to safely call `a.fly()` or `a.bark()` in this case, because you only know you have an Animal, and not what type it is, without inferring and casting to it.

Comment: What does `setId` return? With your latest update, I'm guessing that code would not even compile, unless `setId` returns `this`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get an error because `s` is *declared* to be type `Student`. It doesn't matter that it was *instantiated* as a `new GradStudent()`, the compiler only knows what type `s` was *declared* as. So basically you can only use `s` as if it were a `Student` (you can only use methods defined by the `Student` class).

If you really need to use `.getId()`, you have two options. You can declare `s` as a `GradStudent`:

```
GradStudent s = new GradStudent();
System.out.println(s.getId());
```

Or, you can cast `s` to `GradStudent`:

```
Student s = new GradStudent();
System.out.println(((GradStudent) s).getId());
```

Comment: Thanks! Please look at my edit, because I'm still not entirely sure what's going on.

Comment: The `id` field doesn't get "thrown away", it's still there in `s` (which is _actually_ a `GradStudent`). The compiler just won't allow immediate access, because `s` _looks like_ a `Student`. So yes, if you cast `s` to a `GradStudent`, you will be able to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 4):

The variable

```
Student s
```

is declared as a `Student`, not a `GradStudent`.  You assigned a `GradStudent` instance to the `Student` variable - this does not change the type of said variable.

You could do the following to address the compile time error :

```
Student s = new GradStudent()
((GradStudent)s).getId()
```

but this is considered a code smell.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have got your answer given by above folks. Just wanted to add some points.

Calling method `s.getId()` would end up giving you an error because s is a type of Student and at the compile time compiler checks if `getId()` method exists in Student and if it doesn't find it, will give you an error.

But s is pointing to an object of subtype which is GradStudent and it would be resolved at run time and compiler is unaware of it. So to satisfy compiler you have to downcast s like this

```
((GradStudent)s).getId()
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly because the `GradStudent` has the method `getId()` while `Student` does not.

Your `GradStudent` inherits the `Student` methods but `Student` class only has their OWN methods.

It will work if `GradStudent` implements a `Student` `getId()`

Comment: If `Student` has a `getId()`, will that be called? Or will the `GradStudent` implementation of `getId()` be called?

Comment: Yes, you will get the result of `GradStudent` `getId()` (that overrides the `Student` `getId()`) because of the Inheritance.

Comment: @populationzero In java ,methods always will be resolved based on the type of object , not type of the reference variables. Unlike C++ where methods resolved basis on the type of the reference variables or you have to make the method virtual. In case of java ,methods are by default virtual